# What is the best way to install emacs on windows? so i can add an emacs configuration

Tags: windows, emacs

I've been trying to install emacs and an emacs' configuration from [this tutorial](http://www.braveclojure.com/basic-emacs/) with no success.

Then I installed emacs following this [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g6kgF5ZAf44), but I can't install the emacs configuration from the first link.

How to install emacs properly in Windows, so I can install an emacs configuration?.

Thanks in advance!.

PD: If I want to change my emacs configuration, is It as simple as replace the emacs.d folder?

Comment: What do you mean by "add an emacs configuration"? In what way does it fail?

Comment: In the first tutorial it says that I'm supposed to see some changes when i open emacs, but nothing happens :(

Comment: In emacs, just type `C-x C-f ~/.emacs` and hit return. It will open your config file, and you can make the changes you want.

Comment: I want tu run it with the file configuration I downloaded but It doesn't load the changes from the file.